# Conditionally requiring field in PageBlockTable based on selection checkbox

Tags: rerender, pageblocktable, wrapper-class, required-field

I have a pretty standard use case where I have a PageBlockTable where you can select any number of rows to process.

```
//wrapper class
public class CaseWrapper{
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    public Case case {get; set;}

    public CaseWrapper(){
        selected = false;
    }
}

//VF page
<apex:pageBlockTable id="table" value="{!caseWrappers}" var="caseWrapper">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!caseWrapper.Selected}">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="table" />
        </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
       <apex:inputField value="{!caseWrapper.Status}" required="{!caseWrapper.Selected}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This seems to work until I trigger a required field error and THEN uncheck the selection box.  Instead of becoming un-required again, the required fields stay.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rerendering the entire `pageBlockTable`?

Comment: @NSjonas I belive you should rerender the the entire `<apex:pageBlockTable` not only the `<apex:column`. As the `<apex:column` is dependent on `<apex:pageBlockTable`.

Comment: actually it only half works.  After you trigger a required field, if you unselect it, the field stays required

Comment: actionregion is what you want

Comment: <apex:column does not have required attribute  ? How do you use this in your code ?

Comment: @Prabhat opps, there was a typo when "examplizing" my code.  The required attr is on a inputTextField. I'll correct my question

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping that pageblock table in apex output panel with some 'id' and rerender that apex output panel